# SQL join multiple table

Tags: sql, select

I have 4 tables
A, B, C, D

Table A:

```
 ct_no        ct_type
1010.           1
1011.           1
1012.           2
1013.           3
```

Table B:

```
ct_no.        jcode
1010.           4
1012.           3
1012.           4 
1013.           7
1013.           6
1013.           4
```

Table C:

```
Jcode          jname
4.                   ABC
3.                   lol
7.                   xyz
```

Table D:

```
filno         orno.     fildate.      ct_no
12017.      1.                           1010
12017.      2.                           1010
12017.      3.                           1012
42017.      1.                           1010
```

Now I want table d record with table c jname where table c jcode is 3

Output should be

```
filno   orno ctno  jnames
12017   1    1012  lol,ABC
```

Comment: Whats the relation between table C and D? On what column in table D it should match with table C?

Comment: Is D.orno and C.Jcode a reference ?

Comment: ct_no is main column, but it is not available on table c

Comment: table c and table b are connected on jcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select d.*, c.jname from tabled d 
inner join tableb b on d.ct_no=b.ct_no and b.Jcode=3
inner join tablec c on b.Jcode =c.Jcode
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a couple of joins:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM   d
JOIN   b ON d.ct_no = b.ct_no
JOIN   c ON b.jcode = c.jcode
WHERE  c.jcode = 3
```

Comment: but how do you know the relation which does not exists in original question? I know this might be guess by going based on column names.

Comment: For ctno 1012 there are two jcode 3 and 4 then how to join